# Can National Insurance number and Unique Taxpayer Reference be stored unencrypted in a database?

Tags: encryption, identity-theft

Should these details be stored encrypted, not at all or in plain text in a database?

These are both UK terms, used to identify individuals to the tax authorities; the NI number is used more widely, appearing on payslips for example.

Comment: Can you provide additional context? Many people, myself included, aren't aware of what a national insurance number is or what it is used for. Additionally, what is a unique taxpayer reference? Is it the SSN/EIN? Something else?

Comment: GDPR compliance says these are personal data so if you really must store them, use strong encryption

Comment: @h4ckNinja I've tried to add some context for those not in the UK

Comment: I think the answer is a confident no.

Comment: @IanWarburton If you encrypt the data, where do you store the encryption key?

Comment: @MechMK1 Ain't that the question!

Comment: @IanWarburton That's quite important, and makes "just encrypt it" easier said than done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legalities aside, you should *always* be very careful about how you store personal data. Details like NI number can be used to impersonate individuals (particularly where it stored alongside other identifying information such as names or email addresses) and can lead to identity theft.

- If you don't need the information, don't store it at al
- If you do need it, secure it very carefully. This includes but is not limited to encryption; there is no point spending the time encrypting your database if the application that has access to it has a SQL injection vulnerability that allows someone to enumerate all of the data anyway

Comment: That's good advice. Although SQL injection wouldn't be enough to view data that's encrypted at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the policy of your organization and the compliance standards which your organization have to comply to. This is more of a legal question than an information security question.

However, [NIST-SP 800-122 Guide to Protecting the Confidentiality of Personally Identifiable Information (PII)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-122.pdf) can be used as a general guideline on what level of controls are required.

Comment: "General guideline" indeed - NIST is based the wrong side of the Atlantic to have anything more authoritative to say.